# Unable to publish Angular + Asp.Net core 2.0 using Angular material design

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-core, angular-material

Please help I'm using netcoreapp2.0 with angular 4.4.5, angular-material 2.0.0-beta.12 and angular-cdk 2.0.0-beta.12. All the angular material modules work perfectly in the development of the application, but I get the error below whenever I try to publish the application.

**app.module.shared.ts:**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
    import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
    import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
    import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
    import 'hammerjs';

    @NgModule({
     declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
     ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,

        BrowserAnimationsModule, 
        MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
        { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
      ])
     ]
    })
    export class AppModuleShared {}
```

**Error message:**

```
    ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/dlord/repo/myapp/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/index.d.ts.MatProgressSpinner_Host.html (2,1):
    Property 'DOCUMENT' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Users/dlord/repo/myapp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"'.

    ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/dlord/repo/myapp/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/index.d.ts.MatSpinner_Host.html (2,1): 
    Property 'DOCUMENT' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Users/dlord/repo/myapp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"'.

    ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/@angular/material/button/typings/index.ngfactory.ts
    Module parse failed: C:\Users\dlord\repo\myapp\$$_gendir\node_modules\@angular\material\button\typings\index.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (17:37)


    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
          | import * as i6 from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
          | import * as i7 from '@angular/material/core';
          | export const MatButtonModuleNgFactory:i0.NgModuleFactory<i1.MatButtonModule> = i0.╔╡cmf(i1.MatButtonModule,
          |     ([] as any[]),(_l:any) => {
          |       return i0.╔╡mod([i0.╔╡mpd(512,i0.ComponentFactoryResolver,i0.╔╡CodegenComponentFactoryResolver,
           @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.ngfactory.ts 8:0-109
           @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory.ts
           @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts


    C:\Users\dlord\repo\myapp.csproj(46,5): error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.
```

Comment: Providing the code snippets and error trace is good, but it would extremely helpful if you could provide some insight as to what you have tried to resolve the problem and the outcome of those steps.

Comment: @Hooligancat, thanks for your response. If I uninstall the angular material packages, it gets published successfully using the bootstrap framework.  Also, I added import * as i6 from '@angular/cdk/a11y'; and import * as i7 from '@angular/material/core'; to the app.module.shared.ts but the outcome remains the same.

Comment: Are you publishing to Azure, FTP site or somewhere else?